# How can I get back /usr/local/bin/mysql on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mysql

From terminal and trying to uninstall macports, I ran a command, rm -rf / macports....,  that erased bunch of stuff. I feel ashamed about this, not realizing the space after /.

Since then, mysql is running but I cannot execute any of the mysql commands because it is not under /usr/local/bin/

I went ahead an reinstall mysql but without luck. What steps do you recommend on doing in order to be able to run mysql, mysqlduml, mysqladmin, from terminal? I can access databases from phpmyadmin, so mysql is running, don't ask me how.

Comment: should go to superuser.com, possibly serverfault, but feels like SU to me.

Comment: Do you  have a time machine backup? or any other backup/copy of your previous setup? If not, the data is gone.

Comment: Unless you have a backup you're not going to recover any data. As for the fact your data is running i'm not sure if OSX has daemons but i bet that's where it's starting from.

Answer (score 3):

Should I accidentally run `rm -rf /`, I would certainly go with a **complete re-install** of my system *(1)*. As I would lose any trust in its reliability.

This is the second worst command you can possibly run. The first one being `sudo rm -rf /`. It will simply recursively remove all the files on your disk for which you have read/write permission, that's a show-stopper. Even if you are not an admin user it will still remove some files you can't restore.

Or, as commented by @lexu and @Kravlin, if you have a Time Machine backup, you can try to restore your system as it was before you ran that command. Hope you do have one.

---

*(1) ...and also very likely punch me hard in the face.*

Comment: +1. If you issue "rm -rf /" as root, you have no idea what you damaged. Just trying to bring back a few things you noticed missing, like mysql, while leaving everything else in a fragile unknown state is just a recipe for problems. @Ole, reinstall your system.